# How to add a label and onclick event to a instantiated marker object (instantiated marker object is a prefab object)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-container

I am new to Unity , I want to add a label/text to the prefab object say I want to show city name "Delhi"

Below is the function which I call from Gui button to add the marker to the globe :

```
void AddMarkerGameObjectOnIndia() {
    // Every marker is put on a spherical-coordinate (assuming a radius = 0.5 and relative center at zero position)
    Vector3 sphereLocation;
    map.calc.fromLatDec =  20.59f;  
    map.calc.fromLonDec =  78.96f;  
    map.calc.fromUnit = UNIT_TYPE.DecimalDegrees;
    map.calc.Convert();
    sphereLocation = map.calc.toSphereLocation;
    GameObject pinMarkerObject = Instantiate (Resources.Load<GameObject> ("Marker/PinMarker")); //This is my red marker seen on the globe
    map.AddMarker (pinMarkerObject, sphereLocation, 0.04f);
    // Fly to the destination and see the pinMarkerObjectcreated
    map.FlyToLocation (sphereLocation);
    // Optionally add a blinking effect to the marker pinMarkerObject
    MarkerBlinker.AddTo (pinMarkerObject, 4, 0.2f);
}
```

Now How can i add label to pinMarkerObject  which I Instantiated from a prefab called 'PinMarker' .Is it possible to add tags to each marker pin and when one MarkerPin is clicked I can get the tag of that MarkerPin

Also How can I add onClick event to each Pin

This is my Play scene :

[image: My Marker pins on globe (red icon)]

Comment: Choose one of [Unity's UI Tutorials](https://learn.unity.com/search?k=%5B%22tag%3A581391a30909150018ad9268%22%5D)! In short: You will need a `Canvas` (either one and make all markers childs of this or one for each marker). Then you can simply add `Text` and `Button` elements. The "tag" should not be called by this but ofcourse right where you instantiate a marker you can pass in any information you want and make the button call a method with according "tag" like (later) `newMarker.GetComponentInChildren<Button>(true).onClick.AddListener(()=>DoSomething("example"));`

Comment: make a prefab of the pin which has a canvas and the text, then just set the text

Comment: This is [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].